# when unit testing an asp.net controller, where do you mock the httprequestbase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, mocking, controllers

when unit testing a asp.net controller, don't you have to somehow mock the httpcontextbase?

All my controllers inherit from a custom controller class that I wrote (it just adds some common properties to the original controller class).
So its like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
         // look for a specific cookie
    }

}
```

so really want to start unit testing my controllers, just unsure how I go about mocking the controller classes and the httpcontext that goes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can use Moq to set up a Mock HttpContextBase:

```
var httpCtxStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext();
controllerCtx.HttpContext = httpCtxStub.Object;

sut.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;

// Exercise and verify the sut
```

where `sut` represents the System Under Test (SUT), i.e. the Controller you wish to test.